# Checking a String in an array for brace (java)

Tags: java, braces

so i'm currently trying to check whether or not there's a brace in a String in an array, but I can't figure out how its done.

```
    public void braceChecker()
    {
         String[] code = new String[]{"{} [] () {"};         
         System.out.println(code[0].charAt(0) == "{");
    }
```

Obviously, it errors on the last print statement, but I can't find a way to check that character without java yelling at me. If I take "{" out of the string, it interprets it as an actual brace. How do I go about this?

Comment: Why are you using a 1-element `String[]` and not a `String`?

Answer (score 3):

Change the `"{"` to `'{'` (your want a character literal, not a string literal).

See *Character and String Literals* in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.out.println(code[0].charAt(0) == '{');
```

instead, `""` is a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to single quotes to compare as a character.

Answer (score 0):

A **char** is compared to by using single quotes `'` not double quotes `"` which are used for Strings.

```
public void braceChecker()
{
     String[] code = new String[]{"{} [] () {"};
     System.out.println(code[0].trim());
     System.out.println(code[0].charAt(0) == '{');
}
```